# Not able to run Ionic App with Mobile First 7.1

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created my ionic App via Commmand Prompt by using the following command,

```
   mfp cordova create AppName
```

After that mfp plugin was installed automatically inside my project.Then
I  created mfp project using,

```
 mfp create projectname
```

App created successfully..Then using

> `mfp push`

i pushed my app inside the server 7.1 version.
After i have started to run my ionic app using,

```
 ionic run android --livereload
```

In there i am  getting error as,
    **TypeError: platforms[platformId].parser is not a function**

My configuration:

> cordova : 5.4.1 version android : 3.6.4 version

Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!!

Comment: please . check Ionic docs and MobileFirst cordova docs carefully .

Answer (score 1):

You did not create an Ionic app. You created a Cordova app.
You wrote: `mfp cordova create AppName`. That's not how you create an Ionic app... that's how you do it: `ionic start todo blank`.

Please read the Ionic docs.
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

To create an Ionic app and then integrate it with MobileFirst , you can follow this guide: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/

Comment: can you tell me how to add mfp plugin for 7.1v?
For mfp 8.0 we will use like, 
            cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp      right..like wise...

Comment: Please read the 7.1 tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/

Comment: I have red that tutorial already. That is for creating a cordova app.That time mfp plugin will get installed automatically. But my case is different.I am trying to integrate mfp inside my ionic project!!!!!

Comment: This blog explains it. https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/03/23/working-with-ibm-mobilefirst-and-the-ionic-framework/